# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app in Reactjs on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app

-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

```
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

   NODE_VERBOSE=false

   NODE_ENV=production

   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```

-----> Installing binaries

```
   engines.node (package.json):  10.10.0

   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   

   Resolving node version 10.10.0...

   Downloading and installing node 10.10.0...

   Using default npm version: 6.4.1
```

-----> Installing dependencies

```
   Installing node modules

   

   > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js

   > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

   

   

   > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/ejs

   > node ./postinstall.js

   

   

   > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents

   > node install.js

   

   

   Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported

   

   > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents

   > node install.js

   

   

   Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported

   

   > core-js@3.14.0 postinstall /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/core-js

   > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

   

   

   > core-js-pure@3.14.0 postinstall /tmp/build_8bed3db3/node_modules/core-js-pure

   > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

   

   added 1862 packages in 22.698s
```

-----> Build

```
   Running build

   

   > zitco_cms@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_8bed3db3

   > react-scripts build

   

   Creating an optimized production build...

   Failed to compile.

   

   createRequire is not a function

   Referenced from: BaseConfig
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! zitco_cms@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the zitco_cms@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.qDSBm/_logs/2021-07-13T11_52_35_566Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   

   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:

   https://help.heroku.com/

   

   Love,

   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

!     Push failed

Comment: Building sass is a common problem on more restrictive environments - first thing's first try upgraded to `sass` as `node-sass` is deprecated and compiled differently that is more likely to work out the box

Comment: tried it now im getting a different result in build log with an error message to it

Comment: Also I do wonder why you're trying to compile sass there? Is this for a CI? Normally you would build your app before deploying to a server?